# FusedLocationProviderClient gives inaccurate location

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, location

I have made a simple sample of the FusedLocationProviderClient according to this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates#java

The issue is that I get a location every now and then (waaaay above an interval of 4000ms) and the accuracy is 2000 meters. I need a more precise location and more often. I get the feeling that the location client is not set up properly but at the same time, when using the locationmanager I also get a slow update rate on gps when using the gps provider, network provider also gives me an accuracy of 2000 meters.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {
    Context context;

    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setInterval(4000);
        locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


        fusedLocationClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    Log.e("Got location from provider " + location.getProvider(), location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
                    Log.e("getAccuracy", String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(@NonNull LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
                super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
                Log.e("asdf", "available");
            }
        };

    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, 112);
            return;
        }

        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int i, @NonNull String[] strings, @NonNull int[] ints) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FusedLocationProvider gives wrong location sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413441/fusedlocationprovider-gives-wrong-location-sometimes)

Comment: It kind of does yes